# Loop in property in constructor

Tags: c#, xamarin

If you have a look at my code below. Is there ANY way to write some kind of loop instead of having repeat Row and ColumnDefinitions?

```
var grid = new Grid
            {
                RowSpacing = 12,
                ColumnSpacing = 12,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
            },
                ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
            }
            };
```

Comment: What is the type of `RowDefinitions`?

Comment: Use loops to create an array of rows and an array of columns beforehand and assign these to `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions`?

Comment: @CodeCaster `Enumerable.Repeat()` will return references to the same object, which might not be a good idea in this case (but not knowing the details of `Grid` it's hard to say)

Comment: DOH! Stupid me. Thanks @MatthewWatson!

Comment: @MatthewWatson You should add your obvious solution as an answer which will be accepted as the solution.

Comment: Make sure the obvious solution works before accepting it though.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Allready done!

Comment: I added that as an answer, but it's a little bit shorter than what I usually would consider posting as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use loops to create an array of rows and an array of columns beforehand and assign these to the `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` properties.

I should have thought you'd need to call `RowDefinitions.Add()` and `ColumnDefinitions.Add()` in a loop to do so, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible because the only way this would work is if you could assign a completely new value to the `RowDefinitions` property, which you can't:

```
public RowDefinitionCollection RowDefinitions { get; }
                                                ^^^^
```

The syntax as shown in your question is just a handy way of calling `.Add` on the object in that property, so there is no way for you to inline in that syntax do this. Your code is just "short" for this:

```
var temp = new Grid();
temp.RowSpacing = 12;
temp.ColumnSpacing = 12;
temp.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
temp.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
temp.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
temp.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
... same for columns
```

Specifically, your code is **not** doing this:

```
temp.RowDefinitions = ...
                    ^
```

You would probably want code like this:

```
var grid = new Grid()
{
    RowSpacing = 12,
    ColumnSpacing = 12,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    RowDefinitions = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(_ =>
        new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }),
    ColumnDefinitions = Enumerable.Range(.....
```

But you cannot do this as this would require that `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` was writable.

The closest thing is like this:

```
var temp = new Grid
{
    RowSpacing = 12,
    ColumnSpacing = 12,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
};

for (int index = 0; index < rowCount; index++)
    temp.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
... same for columns
var grid = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

RowDefinitions is RowDefinitionCollection. **RowDefinitionCollection** is internal which you cannot create outside Grid.